# Jquery ToggleClass widthout separating the class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").click(function(){
             $(".ABC").toggleClass("else");
        });

});
</script>


<body>
    <p class="ABC">hahahahhaha</p>
    <input type="button" value="click" />
</body>
```

Runing the above code, the class of `<p>` will be switched between "ABC else" and "ABC" by button clicking.

For example:

1st click: `<p class="ABC">` become `<p class="ABC else">`

2nd click: `<p class="ABC else">` become `<p class="ABC">`

However, I want the classname to be swiched between "ABC" and "ABCelse" **(NO SPACE BETWEEN ABC AND ELSE)**. Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect then? `ABCelse`?

Comment: So you want to *remove* the class `ABC` and *add* the class `ABCelse`?

Comment: why not? just add a new style for `.else`

Comment: then you aren't toggling the class `else` you are removing the class `ABC` and `else` and adding the class `ABCelse'. multiple class selectors on the same element are space separated

Comment: Then you are using the wrong function, it is as simple as that. What would you expect if the element had two classes already, `a b` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this, toggle the ABC class separately from ABCelse.

```
$(this).find(".ABC").toggleClass("ABC").toggleClass("ABCelse");
```

Comment: Thanks,@Brandon. Maybe i didn't clarity it clear. what I want is className "ABCelse" and "ABC" is swiched by clicking button.However, in ur solution "ABCelse" can not be changed to "ABC".

Comment: @emily, I'm confused. In my solution, ABCelse can be changed back to ABC. That is what the toggleClass does. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the reason there is a space between them is because .toggle() is adding the class 'else' to the div. So it now has two classes: .ABC & .else

What you want to do is actually REMOVE the class .ABC and add the class .ABCelse, OR remove the class .ABCelse and add the class .ABC:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.ABC').removeClass('ABC').addClass('ABCelse');
    $(this).find('.ABCelse').removeClass('ABCelse').addClass('ABC');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work once? It removes the original ability to go back and forth between classes since you're explicitly removing and adding classes.

Comment: @Brandon not if the classes get stored in a array or something similar, although I wouldn't do it if I had to choose.

Comment: @Brandon. I've edited my answer. The code I provided will now effectively toggle the classes in the way you want.

Comment: Thanks,@maxedison. but classname can not go back and forth.

Comment: @emily-bcot: Please edit your original question to make things clearer. Everyone seems to be confused about what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":button").click(function(){

    $("div").toggleClass(function(){

        if($(this).is(".ABC")){return "else";}
        else if($(this).is(".else")){return "ABC";}

    });
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DgAPR/